# WebDAV (IIS) Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, webdav

I'm currently building a system where users can list Word and Excel files in an ASP.net webapp and click on files to edit which will open them up in Office from an IIS WebDAV server and allow the users to edit the files.

I have all of this working with Windows Authentication enabled and using the server's hostname to address the file on the WebDAV server:

`ms-word:ofe|u|http://hostname/webdav/myfile.docx`

However the client has a subdomain (resolved by internal dns on their network) and ssl cert they want to use for the site. When I address the file with this domain name:

`ms-word:ofe|u|https://portal.domainname.com/webdav/myfile.docx`

I get a windows authentication prompt when opening it in Word that *will not* accept my domain credentials.

If I switch the WebDAV server to Basic Authentication and set the domain Word will prompt for authentication and *will* accept my domain credentials, but it will prompt on every file I open.

**Is there a way to address the file using this internal subdomain name that will open the files without prompting the user for authentication?**

This will only be accessible on their internal network so I'm open to considering any authentication scheme that would achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of security reasons the client will not send credentials to hosts that are not recognized as local intranet.

When using a (sub)domain instead of a hostname every client has to add the (sub)domain to it's intranet zone:

Internet options > security > Local intranet > Websites > Advanced > Add.
This can also be done by using a Group Policy or setting a registry key.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\microsoft\windows\current version\internet settings\zonemap\domains\[domain]\[subdomain (optional)]
DWORD name: http of https value: 1